# generate weekly report pdf with mpdf - functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress, pdf, mpdf

I'm using mpdf on wordpress for generating PDF files. I'm working on a functionality which will send weekly report to my users and that report should be send as email and pdf will be attached in email.

My issue is that I'm running code in functions.php file because for running this code every week, I'm going to use server side cron job and my function should be inside functions.php file to execute it. So I added this code in functions.php file:

```
function weeklyReportFunc(){
    include('mpdf/mpdf.php');
    $mpdf = new mPDF();
    ob_start();
    require get_template_directory() . '/includes/report.php';
    $x = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($x);
    $today = date('Y-m-d');
    $pdfName = 'weekly-report-'.$today;
    $mpdf->Output($pdfName.'.pdf', 'D');
}
```

And this shows me below error:

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at 
/home/user/public_html/doms/wp-admin/includes/template.php:1995) in /home/user/public_html/
doms/wp-content/themes/mytheme/mpdf/mpdf.php on line 8314

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at 
/home/user/public_html/doms/wp-admin/includes/template.php:1995) in   
/home/user/public_html/doms/wp-content/themes/mytheme/mpdf/mpdf.php on line 1706
mPDF error: Some data has already been output to browser, can't send PDF file
```

How can I solve this? Maybe I need to use my function in some action? but which one? Any ideas please?

Comment: check: /home/user/public_html/doms/wp-admin/includes/template.php:1995 Often the issue is whitespace at the end of a php file (remove php closing tags to prevent this)

Comment: but it is wordpress core file. If I remove php closing tag, then on next update I will need to re-do it. And same on each wordpress update. @SanderBackus

Comment: I checked and on that line (/home/user/public_html/doms/wp-admin/includes/template.php:1‌​995) there is no odd space/closing tag and it is not even the last line of that file. There is php closing/opening tag but it is required to be there. Any other suggestions? @SanderBackus

Comment: Is there any other output happening on that line? Because there should be 0 output before sending headers.

Comment: this is that line content: `<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="ie8 <?php echo $admin_html_class; ?>" <?php` @SanderBackus

Comment: So that's output (the <html tag) . You should prevent the template file from being called then, when generating reports

Comment: let me explain, I have pdfGenerator.php file in my theme folder and there I have above function's same code and it works perfectly because in that php file I have only page template definition and it is attached to a page so that wordpress core functions will be available inside my php file. And now I'm trying to find best solution for this so that I won't hurt wordpress functionality @SanderBackus

Comment: Why do you need the "D" parameter?

Comment: "D" parameter is for download @ShutUpMagda

Comment: Download? In a cron job?

Comment: Download of course won't be in cron job, now I'm trying to make the pdf generated at least without any errors @ShutUpMagda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found solution. So I created a php file in my theme folder and at the very top of the file added `require('../../../wp-load.php');` code which makes all wordpress functions available inside it, even if this file is not a wordpress template page. So as now all functions are available inside this file, I moved my code from functions.php file to this file and I'm already running cron job on this file. Hope this will help someone else.

Comment: I just did that too and it worked, but you should make it a dynamic link rather than ../../../ if it's a distributed plugin for example `require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-load.php';`

Answer (score 0):

Save *report.php* output buffer to `$x` using `exec()`:

```
function weeklyReportFunc(){
    ob_start();
    include('mpdf/mpdf.php');
    $mpdf = new mPDF();
    exec('php -f '.get_template_directory().'/includes/report.php',$output);
    $x = $output[0];
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($x);
    $today = date('Y-m-d');
    $pdfName = 'weekly-report-'.$today;
    $mpdf->Output($pdfName.'.pdf', 'D');
}
```

Comment: Try to use `ob_start()` before calling MPDF class.

Comment: Strange... You should try outside of *functions.php*, just to test.

Comment: "my function should be inside functions.php file to execute it" - Is it because of *Wordpress*?

Comment: yes, but now I'm trying to move that function into a blank page and add cron job for that page @ShutUpMagda

Comment: Yep. Too much better ;)